# Radio button with jQuery and AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I've got the following error when i'm sending the form, to be exact with radio button input.

Here is the HTML Code:

```
      <input name="radio" type="radio" class="raido-btn" id="coral1" value="coral1" />
      <label for="coral1">CORAL I</label>
      <input name="radio" type="radio" class="raido-btn" id="coral2" value="coral2" />
      <label for="coral2">CORAL II</label>
      <input name="radio" type="radio" class="raido-btn" id="coral3" value="coral3" />
      <label for="coral3">CORAL III</label>
```

Here is the Javascript code:

```
if($('#coral1').prop('checked')){
        apartamentos = 'Coral 1';
    }
    else if($('#coral2').prop('checked')){
        apartamentos = 'Coral 2';
    }
    else if($('#coral3').prop('checked')){
        apartamentos = 'Coral 3';
    }
```

I don't know how to set the variable "apartamentos" to the radio button which is checked.

It always set the variable apartamentos = 'Coral'

Thanks in advance

Comment: `apartamentos = $('.raido-btn:checked').val()`

Comment: With that always set apartamentos = 'Coral 1'

Comment: All your radios have the same name, only one can be checked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JQuery has a few ways to do this. One way I usually do it is by using [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/), for example, `$('#coral2').is(':checked')`. You could also use `apartamentos = $('.raido-btn:checked').val()`

Comment: Going to try first option but with the second option always sets the variable apartamentos = 'Coral 1';

Comment: You should be able to do $("#coral2").checked and avoid little jquery overhead =)

Comment: Thank you. I add onclick="$('#coral1').checked" for every input now works perfect ;)

Answer (score 2):

What are you attaching that if statement to? I attached it to the clickevent in jsFiddle and and it seems to be working fine. I'm not sure if you want `apartamentos` to be set to the value of the radio button or the strings that you defined, but it's definitely being updated.

http://jsfiddle.net/FTT5e